# People who do kung fu, wushu, taekwondo, aerobics

Tags: word-request

I know I can use *martial artists* to describle people doing them. Is it possible to be more accurate while describing these athletes? So far I've found *karateka /kəˈrɑːtɪkɑː/* but trying to look up the other major martial artists practicing kung fu, wushu, taekwondo was in vain.

Can I use compound nouns *X martial artist* as in *kung fu martial artist* to describe these athletes?

Then it came to me what a person doing aerobics is called. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I usually see: "**practitioner(s) of Tae Kwon Do**" (or other martial art) ... or maybe ... "**Tae Kwon Do artist**".
If you want to be very informal, you could say "**Tae Kwon Do-ist**", but that is non-standard.  **Karateka** is a Japanese word.  Most English speakers don't know what it means, but if your audience is familiar with the martial arts they probably will know. Keep in mind that you can use the **-ka** ending with other Japanese martial arts as well, as in **Judoka**.

Comment: I assume you think of applying the same logic to _kung fu_ and _wushu_ e.i. for informal references _kung fuist_ or _wushuist_ would work. What about _aerobics_? I'd appreciate if you include that one too.

Comment: *Kung fuist* sounds very odd to this US English speaker.  A web search turns up almost no use of it.  **Practitioner of** sounds better, as Stew C said, or maybe *student of*.

Comment: I object to the statement "most English speakers don't know what [karateka] means.". Karateka was a hit video game in the US in the mid 1980's. Karate was the catch-all term used in the United States to describe all martial arts beginning in the 60's and 70's. The Karate Kid movies are classics. There are too many examples.

Comment: @Yuri As stangdon comments, it sounds a bit weird to me too.  It sounds like a made-up word, which it is.  That's why I called it **very** informal.  You might want to stick to "wushu artist" instead.  Oh, also possible is "wushu player" if the person does competitions, which has more flair.

Comment: @Stew C The best way I think will be _practitioner of_ that you already suggested. I get a fair number of hits at least I know some people somewhere say that :) I upvoted you for the answer. Thank you its been really helpful.

Answer (score 1):

For aerobics, there is a word *aerobicist*, however it doesn't have much definition:

> Definition of aerobicist in English:
>
> aerobicist
>   noun
>
> See aerobics

[From Lexico, powered by Oxford](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/aerobicist)

It's the word I thought of, and there are a few references to it, but normally separate from aerobics from what I have seen.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time 